# Java code in Netbeans IDE: Code executed is the older one! even when I make changes in the code

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee

I am building an application in Java using Netbeans IDE. I am trying to debug some errors in my code. But even when I modify messages passed in the log statements, I do not see a corresponding change in the logged messages. This implies that when execute the code, it probably runs an older version of code & prints the old version of log messages as well.

What is the cause of this error ? & how should I rectify this ?

Thanks for helping..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saving the code. I assume, you are have compile-on-save enabled. If not then you have to build it before running it.

Yes you need to enable build-on-save, otherwise GlassFish wouldn't be able to show you the changes, because the new changes have never been deployed. Sometimes, deploying on save bothers a lot. So, what I do is, I don't enable build-on-save and work with tests and thereby run my tests to see the result of the change. When everything seems fine, then I build the app and deploy it on the server for further verifications.

Comment: I am writing a web app thus Previously I had "deploy on save" enabled, but I had disabled it since I was not building/running the entire project but just a single file from it. So even if am not using the Glassfish server do I need to enable 'deploy on save' ?? Thanks

Comment: @Marcos: Yes you need to do that, otherwise GF wouldn't be able to show you the changes, because the new change has never been deployed. Sometimes, deploying on save bothers a lot. So, what I do is, I don't enable deploy-on-save and work with tests and thereby run my tests to see the result of the change. When everything seems fine, then I build he app and deploy it on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I had that same problem...closing and reopening netbeans fixed it for me...

Comment: Thanks mixkat ! Although this solved the problem for now but I doubt whether I would be able to work properly with Netbeans living with this problem! Isnt there any permanent solution for this ?

Comment: I didnt happen to me again...donno what was causing it...Just to be sure check your settings as Adeel ansari suggested...although if you havent changed the defaults it shouldnt have a problem..

Answer (score 0):

Compile on save must be set.
See the properties of your project. 
(Right click, select properties, then select compile).
Another possibility is that you have to  redeploy
your project. In such a case I would recommend to
take a look at jRebel.